# UnknownHostException Error in HTML report

Tags: jmeter, unknown-host

I am trying to generate HTML report using one of the Jmeter test script. I have a JMX file which works fine in Jmeter and Jmeter provide success status when I run the script. I have setup ANT with Jmeter successfully. Now, I am trying to generate HTML report using ANT from command prompt. when I run this command ant -Dtest=script name, it generate HTML report in the same folder.. But all the items in the HTML reports shows error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

check your version of the Jmeter if its 3.0 it might not work. As Jmeter devs broke this functionality. Now to get it to working all you have to do is copy

> jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl from Jmeter 2.13 extras folder to Jmeter 3.0 extras

And update Build.xml in extras folder to reflect this change

```
    <tstamp><format property="report.datestamp" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"/></tstamp>
   <xslt
        classpathref="xslt.classpath"
        force="true"
        in="${basedir}/${test}.jtl"
        out="${basedir}/Test.html"
        **style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl">**
        <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
        <param name="titleReport" expression="${report.title}"/>
        <param name="dateReport" expression="${report.datestamp}"/>
    </xslt>
</target>
```

Comment: check the ** line thats the only change required.